# Returning value from a page class function in Cypress and using it another page class function

Tags: asynchronous, cypress

I'm trying to return a value from one page class function and to use it in another page class function.

But when I try returning primitives value; its always shows as undefined as cypress commands are asynchronous and return statement is synchronous. When I tried aliases the aliases in page class 1 is not visible in page class-2.

What is the correct way of returning values from page class function in cypress. Below is sample code.

```js
     /// <reference types="Cypress" />

     import Page1 from "../pages/Page1";
     import Page2  from "../pages/Page2";

     let page1 = new Page1();
     let page2 = new Page2();

     describe('SampleTesSuite', function(){

     beforeEach(() => {
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.visit("https://cypress.io");
        cy.log("Application launched")
        cy.viewport(1280, 1024)
    });

    it('Test1', function(){

     let divTitle = page1.getValue();
     page2.processValue(divTitle);
     
    });

    });
```

```js
    /// <reference types="Cypress" />

    class Page1
    {

     getValue()
     {  
        let divTitle;

        cy.get("section[class^='Hero']  div[class='container']>h1>div")
          .invoke('text').then((text) => {
            divTitle = text;
          });

        return divTitle;
      }
     }

     export default Page1;
```

```js
    /// <reference types="Cypress" />

    class Page2
    {
      processValue(title)
      {
        cy.log("The value fetched from Pageclass-1"+title);
      }

    }

      export default Page2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return synchronous value from asynchronous code. Once part of your method is async, then method return value is async and must be treated as such.

**page1**

```js
getValue() {  
  // returns a wrapped version of the text
  return cy.get("section[class^='Hero'] div[class='container'] > h1 > div")
    .invoke('text')
}
```

**test**

```js
page1.getValue().then(divTitle => {  // wrapped text must be accessed with .then()
  page2.processValue(divTitle);
})
```

---

You can make use of an alias with `.as()`, but it's still async code.

**page1**

```js
getValue() {  
  // no return value, but sets a Cypress alias (asynchronously)
  cy.get("section[class^='Hero'] div[class='container'] > h1 > div")
    .invoke('text')
    .as('divTitle')
}
```

**test**

```js
page1.getValue()
cy.get('@divTitle').then(divTitle => {  
  page2.processValue(divTitle);
})
```

Since you use `it('...', function() {` the alias value will be available as `this.divTitle`.

However, it's still async so you access it like this

**test**

```js
page1.getValue()
cy.then(() => {    // cy.then() waits for the alias value to be set
  page2.processValue(this.divTitle);
})
```

Comment: Both these options work, but using arrays instead of primitives also work. Any reason why  pushing values in arrays work and not primitives?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that works with your given example - can you add it?

Comment: There is potential for using a [reference variable](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/), which means array, object, or function. For example, use the `Cypress` global as a reference object (e.g in page1 `Cypress.divTitle = divTitle`). But it's still asynchronous, which dictates that you have to wait for the `cy.get()` to complete before accessing the property on the reference variable.

Comment: Would like to see better details about how you made arrays work.

Comment: below solution works with arrays

Comment: Both Arrays and Map works because its passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import Page1 from "../pages/Page1";
import Page2  from "../pages/Page2";

let page1 = new Page1();
let page2 = new Page2();

describe('SampleTesSuite', function(){

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.clearCookies();
        cy.visit("https://cypress.io");
        cy.log("Application launched")
        cy.viewport(1280, 1024)
    });

    it('Test1', function(){

     let titles = page1.getValue();

     page2.processValue(titles);

    });

});

/// <reference types="Cypress" />

class Page1
{

    getValue()
    {  
       let titles = [];

        cy.get("section[class^='Hero']  div[class='container']>h1>div").invoke('text').then((text) => {
            titles.push(text);
        });

        return titles;
   }
}

export default Page1;

/// <reference types="Cypress" />

class Page2
{
    processValue(titles)
    {
       cy.then(() => {
           cy.log("The value fetched from Page-1 is="+titles[0])
        });
    }

}

export default Page2;
```

Comment: Yes, but you cheated :). You added `cy.then(...)` to Page 2, so really it's not the array but because you are now handling async correctly.